# Proper way to display numbers in Arabic

Tags: internationalization, arabic, right-to-left, arabic-support

Our ecommerce website is international and we're currently adding support for Arabic right-to-left text. What is the standard for displaying dynamic numerals? For instance, for static marketing copy like "500 units produced" I can see displaying "500" using Eastern Arabic numerals, but what about dynamic numerals like order totals, quantities, etc? The simplest way is obviously to stick to the familiar Hindu-Arabic (Western) numerals (1234...), but I'm unsure what the industry standard is.

For reference, our application is a mix of standard Java and jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any "industry standard" around this kind of thing. But typically if you want to localize numbers in Java, you'll want to use a NumberFormat with your desired Locale. In JavaScript, assuming you have `Intl.NumberFormat` available, you'd use that to do the same. For example:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("ar-SA").format(50.0) 
=> '٥٠'
```

Note, in case you didn't already know, that "٥" is "5" and "٠" is "0". This is not a mistake. Eastern Arabic numerals are read from their lowest value to their highest value going right to left, so they appear to be in the same "direction" as in English (i.e. the highest value is on the left).

As to whether you can "get away" with using Western numerals instead, it will depend on your target market. For example, Apple embeds strings like "64-bit" and lists millimeters (مم) with Arabic numerals in their [Saudi localization](https://www.apple.com/sa-ar/iphone/compare/), and the [UAE's government website](https://government.ae/ar-ae) uses Arabic numerals all over the place.

(I am not a native Arabic speaker, I'm just a student, so I'm not really able to say what native Arabic speakers expect; just what I see in Arabic writings I come across. I'll leave it to actual Arabic speakers to give more guidance there.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Arabic speaker, but I am a native Urdu speaker.

> In Urdu, numbers are written the same way
> (though numerals are slightly different)

For instance,

> 50 mm

is written as:

> "٥٠" on the right (in Arabic, not Urdu)

> and "مم" on the left

(Writing it directly wasn't working on this site)